# Limiting the number of trials in combination Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, combinations

The following code calculates all the results of `5C4` (5 combination 4) as a string:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
result_array = a.combination(4).map(&:join).to_a
```

Is there a method I can use to limit the number of combination trials, similarly to the `itertools` module in Python?

Comment: If you wish to take the first so-many combinations is there a reason you want to construct an array as opposed to simply having the enumerator pass the first `n` elements to another enumerator or a block?

Comment: what i'm doing is actually making combinations between different 4 groups, so if I use calling enumerator in enumerator, I thought it causes so many overlaps. @Cary Swoveland

Comment: If you mean that you wish to generate the first so many 4-tuples obtained by drawing one element from each of 4 arrays, that would be a different problem, albeit an interesting one. If so, please consider posting another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
result_array = a.combination(4).lazy.map(&:join).take(2).to_a
```

`lazy` will ensure that you only compute as many values as needed by `take`.

Comment: @jh-shin Please note that the location of the `lazy` call was wrong previously, I shouldn't post here before coffee...

Comment: no prob. I've figured it out. thanks for alarming me about `lazy`